# For Android Map api v2 Description references non existing library google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar

Tags: android, google-api, android-mapview, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have import google-play-services_lib into my workspace and Add google project into MYProject it give mr error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Android
>   Workspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'  HBuddy      Build
>   path  Build Path Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project cannot be built
>   until build path errors are resolved  HBuddy      Unknown Java Problem

and I have already installed Google Play Service in Extras [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get it resolved? Could you share the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please uncheck "Is Library" as follows ;

[image]

Comment: Try select your project with your mouse < right-click < Android Tools < Add Support Library. Then Project < clean..

Comment: You must import 'google-play-services_lib" from your work space and be able to see it within your Package Explorer window of eclipse. And the folder of 'google-play-services_lib" exists within your works space folder.

Comment: @BBonDoo I did all this, and it's still not working. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 17):

I met this issue as well.

My solution is,

1. clean project **google-play-services_lib** firstly
2. then clean my project which depends on play service library

Answer (score 4):

Hey i know what your problem is. I think it seems like you didn't built your google-play-services project... Try the following solution:

1. Import the google-play-services_lib "project" into your workspace
2. Add the freshly imported project to your applications build path
3. RIGHT-CLICK the google-play-services_lib project and select "Build Project"
4. Wait a few moments or "clean up" your project
5. Run your application and - Voila -

Comment: @satine kianne - Thanks for your upvote! I hope i cold help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your bin folder doesn't exist! You probably don't have permission to create a folder.

If you create a project from existing code make sure you check "Copy projects into workspace".

Answer (score 1):

I found that the reference is looking at the wrong folder. It normally looks in `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/bin/` for the jar file and the file is actually inside the `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs` folder. I couldn't find a way to change the reference link, so I just copied the jar file and the matching jar properties file from the `/libs` folder to the `/bin` folder.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The /libs folder probably contains google-play-services.jar. However, the problem description refers to \bin\google-play-services_lib.jar. (Note the filenames differ.) Although copying the jar file from libs into bin might not hurt, it doesn't deal with the problem. Instead, you could run android update project -p . in the google-play-services_lib (to generate local.properties and a build.xml), then run the build. This will generate the missing jar. However, this is still just a workaround, treating the symptom, not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is,

1. clean project google-play-services_lib firstly
2. then clean my project which depends on play service library

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to resolve this issue. Import google_play_services_lib project to your work space.
android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Then add the google-play-services.jar file externally.
right click on your_project -> properties ->java build path -> Libraries -> add External JARs -> select  google-play-services.jar from work space ->clean ->build

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and got it solved when I updated my eclipse Android SDK tools.
I was using version 22 and when I updated Android SDK tools to 22.0.1 the error vanished and I could build my project.
I  hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

Check Read Only property of the Project folder.
If its checked, uncheck it and then try.