# Android Dependencies Issue

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am writing a MAP APP using Android Google Maps V2

But i am facing dependency problem, please see below images:

[image]

as you can see in above screen shot i am getting **RedAlert**  Sign *over Project Name*

[image]

and as you can see in above screen shot getting **RedCross** over *Android Dependencies*

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or a transcript from Eclipse 'Problems' window? You can open it by means of the `Window | Show View` menu command.
Most probably you need to create a folder named `libs` and copy your  dependencies into it. It is the default location of `Android Dependencies`.

Comment: There should be an error description in 'Problems' section of Eclipse, post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ChulbulPandey

In Eclipse open **Project -> Properties**. Select Android on left. Check on the bottom that you have a reference to Google play services with a green checkmark. If not, click Add and add the google play services library

Path of google-play-services_lib at SDK;

**\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib**

Comment: @ChulbulPandey Google APIs is not required for Maps API v2. It was used for (now deprecated) API v1.

Comment: @MaciejGórski is right. Your problem should not be solved by using google apis.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this.

In Libraries tab remove the Google Maps V2 jar and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing **project build target** to something higher and then clean then build your project.

If that doesn't solve your issue then removing your external jar files linked and then import it again.

Answer (score 0):

You must import `google-play-services_lib` library project from SDK and add a dependency to it from your project.

Path of google-play-services_lib at SDK;

`\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122358/android-dependencies-references-non-existing-library-google-play-services-lib-ja)